# mongodb map reduce output - failed no output or partial output

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

if something goes wrong when mapreduce is outputing on temp collection, what's happen?

Is it present no output in temp collection? or is it present a partial output, so no consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map reduce should never output partial results.  If a Map Reduce operation fails mid-stream, an error message will be generated.  Any temporary files that have been generated will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Is this a general principle of map/reduce? or are you referring to just MongoDB?

Comment: In this case, I can only speak for MongoDB.